# Search synonym pointing to redirect in magento

Tags: magento, redirect, search

Does anyone know if it is possible to let a Magento (ver.1.7) search synonym point to the redirect page that the synonym is pointing to? It looks like the default is that when pointing to a synonym it only show search result like if you searched for the word it is synonym for - and not to the redirect link that the synonym search is pointing to.

An example:

search term "bicukle" -> synonym "bicycle"

search term "bicycles" -> synonym "bicycle"

search term "bycicle" -> synonym "bicycle"

search term "bicycle" -> redirect to "http://store-url.com/my_bicycle_page.html"

My idea is that they all in a way point to the redirect-page, and that if (or when) i will have to do changes to the search redirect for "bicycle", this then will affect all the typo-variants of bicycle that is having bicycle as a synonym (without having to change ALL the search terms).

But what I am experiencing is that even if I configure the search terms like above, only "bicycle" points to the redirect page. The other searches points to the search term "bicycle" *without* any redirect.

Anyone know? Thanks!
-Espen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synonym function is a one-pass function before it goes on to the next step which is searching for the term in the **synonym field** or redirecting to the URL listed in the **redirect URL field**. There is no recursion where one synonym will match to another till you get to the "right page".

If you want bicycle to redirect to a page as your rule

```
search term "bicycle" -> redirect to "http://store-url.com/my_bicycle_page.html"
```

And you want all the language variants/misspellings listed in **Search Terms** maintenance to redirect as well, then you will need to duplicate that URL redirect rule for all the other entries.

Also, the **redirect URL** field has precedence, so if you have an entry in the **synonym** field, it will be ignored.